Single pole & 3 way switch to one light
I have a single pole (black & white wire) going to a light. I would like to add another switch to the light.
Many thanks to all.

You will need to add new wires/cables in the walls/ceiling.  Besides that, it should be easy.

Key question: Does the existing switch box have: 1 cable = black and white wires both going to the switch or 2 cables = 2 black wires going to the switch and 2 white wires connected to each other? Makes a big difference. If you're not sure, a picture of the switch box (turn off the breaker and pull the switch out for pictures, but do not disconnect any wires) will help.

Might not be allowed to not add 12/3 to the old/current switch if it is the old style switch loop.  New switch circuits require a neutral wire in the box.

consider a wireless remote switch.
